# Export table of multiple categorical variables with same categories to excel

Tags: stata, export-to-excel, categorical-data, tabulate

I need to export an overview of several categorical variables to Excel. Even though it appears so trivial there have been roadblocks a lot by now. I have been looking at different options, like `tabout`, [tab2xl](https://blog.stata.com/2018/06/07/export-tabulation-results-to-excel-update/) or [putexcel](https://blog.stata.com/2017/01/24/creating-excel-tables-with-putexcel-part-2-macro-picture-matrix-and-formula-expressions/) but because of the combination of having multiple variables that are categorical in nature I have been unable to apply any of the solutions proposed in other threads to my case.

Because all the variables have the same categories, I would like to have them all in one table. The user-written command `tabm` gives me exactly the output I need:

```
set obs 50

local vlist v1 v2 v3 v4 v5

foreach v of local vlist { 
    generate byte `v' = 1
    replace `v' = 2 if _n>10
    replace `v' = 3 if _n>20
    replace `v' = 4 if _n>30
}


label define valuelabels 1 "Label 1" 2 "Label 2" 3 "Label 3" 4 "Label 4" 
label values v1-v5 valuelabels

tabm v*
```

[The tabm command gives me this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TUlM.png)

But now I want Stata to automatically export this into Excel. Because the dataset I am working with is subject to a lot of changes, it's not an option to just [manually copy](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1532279-export-tabm-to-excel) the table every time.

Comment: `tabm` is a community-contributed command from `tab_chi` on SSC. The help explains that the results can `replace` the data in memory using that option. So, that then allows you to export the results as readable in Excel in any way you like. You could clone the program and insert commands to do that directly. (I am its author and don't tend to support that kind of export in my own code.)

Comment: You link to https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1532279-export-tabm-to-excel which doesn't really give a different response. The flavour of this seems to that you want someone to write code for you, and sometimes that works here and some times it doesn't. Most of the questions here that work well have specific code by the poster that isn't quite working as desired and want a focused reply on what to do differently.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Nick. I'll try finding a solution using the `replace` option, although I'm not sure yet how I can use this option to export the table rather than just the underyling data. Also, I hear what you say about posting a code that only needs specifications. But sometimes you just can't find a command that even has the potential to solve your problem (in this case, none of the mentioned commands seems to be able to deal with multiple categorical vars). More experienced users may have a quick idea to such problems - doesn't have to be fully written code, just some idea.

Comment: Understood, but in principle you don't even need the `replace` option. You just need to decide what kind of export you want and put that in your own command that can be based on `tabm`. The code is there to be modified; it's not a black box.

Comment: I note that "export to Excel" doesn't mean one single and simple thing, which is reason enough why user-programmers like myself often don't even try to provide it. As you want lots of these tables, you should have very detailed ideas about what metadata to export too, and so on and so forth. Stata provides tools enough to export and it's an individual programmer's job to decide which they want. Sorry if that seems unhelpful, but although "export to Excel" is simple words, it's the details that matter here.